# Controlling the "minOccurs", "maxOccurs" and "use" attributes in a type definition in the WSDL generated for an ASP.NET Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization, asmx

Is there any way to control the `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` attributes of the definition of an element, or the `use` attribute of the definition of an attribute, in the WSDL generated for an ASP.NET Web Service?

I know it is possible to do this using custom XML Serialization (i.e., making each class implement `IXmlSerializable` and have the `XmlSchemaProviderAttribute` attribute), but this would be very time consuming, especially taking into consideration this Web Service defines many types and operations.

```
public class TestA
{
    public int Field1;    // minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" (good)
    public string Field2; // minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" (not good)
                          // I would like minOccurs to be "1" as well
}

public class TestB
{
    [XmlAttribute()] public int Field1;    // use="required" (good)
    [XmlAttribute()] public string Field2; // no use attribute (not good)
                                           // I need use="required"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the minOccurs

[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
public int Field2;